# Cognos Report - same query multiple times with different parameters to multiple tabs of 1 XLS

Tags: cognos-10

I need to produce a Cognos Report that produces 12 tabs. Each tab contains the same sort of report simply run for a different parameter value, for example, the month of the current year. I would like to reuse the SQL and define it only once and have this SQL accept a parameter.

I'm very new to Cognos 10 Report Studio. Can I use the Event Manager to execute a single report once with 13 parameters but yet combine the results in a sdingle XLS with 12 tabs?

I know I can split the results of a single query across multuiple XLS tabs, but i need to run the same query multiple times with different parameters...

I've only seen a 5 min demo of Event Mgt, not sure if that's even the place. Any direction to a newbie would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how "different" the parameters are.

If you want to split the values of one data item across separate tabs, such as a tab for each month of the year, use `Page Sets`. Write one query, create one list/report object. Then `Section` the list and tie to the `Page Set` construct in the `Page` tab. [Example](http://www.stthomas.edu/media/informationresourcestechnologies/pdf/Cognos_8_Page_Breaks.pdf)

A report created in Report Studio with different `Pages` will also export to different Excel tabs. If you have to split on a combination of 2+ data items with different values, you'll have to use different pages and queries. You can't re-use one query and plug in different values for each page. So, copy the primary query object and re-write to use  parameter(s) unique to each page. Your prompt page may get a little large, but this is the standard method to create a "book" of reports.

Event Manager is for triggering report execution based off changing data. The classic example is to send a "Thank You" note to a salesman when he logs a sale of $1m or more in the database.